# Sysbench on Azure MySQL - SQL error, errno = 2013, state = 'HY000': Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, azure-mysql-database, sysbench

I am having trouble with running sysbench on Azure DB for MySQL. I have a sysbench server on a Azure VM which I am using to connect to Azure MySQL server through remote host. I have used this same sysbench server setup to benchmark another VM on Azure without this issues, but have been receiving the error on Azure DB for MySQL. I have modified below server parameters as well, but the issue persists.

- max_allowed_packet           536870912 --> 1073741824
- wait_timeout                 120 --> 2147483
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout     50 --> 1073741824
- net_read_timeout             120 --> 31536000
- net_write_timeout            240 --> 31536000

The sysbench command has been modified to test if it allows to insert even just 1 entry but is still failing.

```
sudo sysbench /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_write.lua --mysql-host=<hostname> --mysql-port=3306 --mysql-user=<username>
--mysql-password=<password> --mysql-db=sysbenchmark --db-driver=mysql --tables=1 --table-size=1 --threads=1 prepare

**OUTPUT**
sysbench 1.0.17 (using system LuaJIT 2.0.4)

Creating table 'sbtest1'...
FATAL: mysql_drv_query() returned error 2013 (Lost connection to MySQL server during query) for query 'CREATE TABLE sbtest1(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  k INTEGER DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  c CHAR(120) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  pad CHAR(60) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) /*! ENGINE = innodb */ '
FATAL: `sysbench.cmdline.call_command' function failed: /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_common.lua:197: SQL error, errno = 2013, state = 'HY000': Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: look at the server mysql error log. Except for max_allowed_packet, most other vars shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Nothing on either the mysql logs on the sysbench server or mysql logs on the Azure portal. Also, except for the max_allowed_packet, I have reverted all the other changes.